# Updating data with new line in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working on a school projcet:

I have a project that create reports using data from a table in a database. The table contain info about a customer, such as address/name etc. I am trying to update the name of the customer for the report by updating the table in the database. However, new name is two lines instead of one.

Example, current name is "University Fun Club" and the current report uses this as the name of the customer for the report. Example:

```
Report to:
University Fun Club
```

I would like it to show:

```
Report to:
3rd Division
University Fun Club
```

Is it possible to update the data in the table to:

```
"3rd Division 
University Fun Club"
```

?

Comment: Formatting data is really the domain of the reporting tool or application consuming the data. You can store the data with a new line (ascii 13) character but it's down to the report to interperet it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a literal newline in your insert.

> ```
> create table test (col1 varchar(100));
> insert into test values
> ('3rd Division
> University Fun Club');
> ```

> ```
> select col1 "Report to:" from test
> ```

> ```
> | Report to:                          |
> | :---------------------------------- |
> | 3rd Division
> | University Fun Club                 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d7ab1c140c9011945db830db5fd1950)*